# React app injecting into js instead of index.html

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I would like to create a React app that will not be a standalone site, but rather an extension to an existing site. The site is built using asp.net and I cannot make edits to it. I do have an entry with javascript and can run code such as the following:

```
$(document).onload(() => {
  $(body).parent().append(`
    <script src='{...}'></script>      
  `);
});
```

Is there any way I can change the standard `Index.html` output from the default `create-react-app` to a `.js` file and have the react chunks added into the append? It does not necessarily need to follow the above direction, but it's as far as I got.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could just attach it to the body using ReactDOM.render

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React>
    <App />
  </React>,
  document.getElementByTagName('body')
)
```

But you might have to switch away from `create-react-app` to using webpack, and then use something like `HTMLWebpackPlugin` within your `webpack.config.js` to specify the entry point

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: "[name]/[name].js",
  },
  ...
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './html/index.html',
        filename: './index.html'
      }),
  ...
}
```

You would have to install `html-webpack-plugin` as well as `webpack` and anything you need with `npm install html-webpackplugin webpack ...`

---

If you look up tutorials on this, try to find `React 17` and `Webpack 5` they're fairly new. `Webpack 5` has some differences with hot reloading compared to Webpack 4